# Can't connect to localhost using mysql-connector-python, error 1130

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, mysql-connector-python, mysql-error-1130

I'm trying to connect to a local mysql database from pyhton using the `mysql-connector-python`. The mysql server is set up to allow only local connections. It works with many other applications, but not in my python script. I'm using the following:

```
db_config = {'host': 'localhost', 'user': 'aaa', 'password': 'xxx', 'database': 'aaa'}
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
```

and I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1130: Host 'static-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.net.upcbroadband.cz' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

where `static-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.net.upcbroadband.cz` is a hostname corresponding to my public static ip address.

I tried changing the `host` parameter to `127.0.0.1`, but it didn't help.

Interestingly, when I try to login from the terminal: `mysql -h localhost -u aaa -p`, there is no problem, however, when I do: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u aaa -p`, I get the same error,

```
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'static-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.net.upcbroadband.cz' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Is it possible, that `mysql-connector-python` somehow converts the localhost to public ip?

Comment: Check your `host` file, it may have localhost mapped to public IP

Comment: I thought so as well, but no - hosts file is normal. Moreover, there are no issues when using the `mysql -h localhost -u aaa -p` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, `MASQUERADE` was set up for all external packets:

```
sudo iptables --table nat --list

[...]
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.0.0.0/8           anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

When I removed it by `sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`
the problem was solved.

I actually figured this out when trying

```
mysql -h localhost --protocol=TCP
```

which again produced the 1130 error resolving localhost to public hostname. That means, if I understand it correctly, that `mysql-connector-python` is using TCP by default contrary to the `mysql` command.